# Which code is MSIL? Is the code generated by ILDASM MSIL?

Tags: c#, compiler-construction, .net-assembly

I am still confused with which code is called as MSIL.

Among other compilers, C# produces an assembly.
ILASM also produces an assembly.
Those assemblies contain MSIL?

How about the code generated by ILDASM when taking an assembly as its input?
Is the generated code called MSIL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MSIL is the "machine code like" language that the C# compiles your code
into.

The CLR is the "machine" that the MSIL runs on.

When runinng the MSIL the CLR converts your code into *real* machine code
using the JIT.

The real machine code is run on your computers actual CPU.

The [MSIL Assembler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/496e4ekx%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) (Ilasm.exe) generates a portable executable (PE) file from Microsoft intermediate language (MSIL). ILDASM is the disassembler to do the opposite.

The PE format is used for EXE, DLL, SYS (device driver), and other file types.

Comment: Just a confirmation question. If someone asks me to write a simple program in MSIL then I have to write something that looks like the code generated by ILDASM (by taking an assembly of the program produced by c# (for example) compiler as ILDASM input)?

Comment: Theoretically writing the MSIL as ILDASM presents it would work although I think you will have more success with [Rewrite MSIL Code on the Fly with the .NET Framework Profiling API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc188743.aspx) and this looks useful too http://csharpcomputing.com/Tutorials/Lesson8.htm

Answer (score 2):

MSIL = Microsoft Intermediate Language

MSIL is the output of all .NET compilers. It can be expressed as MSIL assembly code or in binary form - the latter is what you find inside compiled assemblies.

Answer (score 2):

The C# Compiler generates an Assembly. The Assembly contains meta-data, and MSIL. The VB.NET (now referred to simply as VB) generates the same thing. The C/C++ Compiler can create MSIL as well. The IL Assembler (ILASM) can take IL and generate an Assembly.

ILDASM is a disassembler. You can find details documenting the IL (MSIL) [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes_fields.aspx).

Comment: So ILDASM can be regarded as MSIL viewer (to view the MSIL in an assembly)?

Comment: Correct. You can view the IL, and do so by opening the various Classes. Compile up a simple HelloWorld app and then open it using ILDASM HelloWorld.exe